# DPDT toggle AND WiFi relay - how do I do it?

Tags: relay, wiring, wifi, dpdt

As the title states I'm trying to wire BOTH a DPDT toggle switch (on off on) and a WiFi relay.

Situation is as follows: I have a motorized ball valve which operates via a DPDT switch. There are five wires which control it. 2 for the valve motor and polarity, 2 for status lights open and closed, and 1 for valve status power. See the attached video for the wiring and below for an image of the current wiring https://youtu.be/_n8HoSkzl5w

The valves open and close based on the polarity reversal of the DPDT switch.

So currently I have the wires crossed in the back of the DPDT switch (top left bottom right and vice versa) with power flowing into the switch. I generally flip it on, let the valve open, then flip it to off to cut any power to the valve (as it retains position).

Im trying to figure out how to add (not replace with) a 12 V WiFi relay to let me do the same thing via my phone when I'm away, but also retain the functionality of the physical DPDT switch.

Optimally, the DPDT switch could be in the off position or any position when using the wifi switch, and the WiFi app will read the actual status of the valve.

I'm a total newbie so any diagrams how to do this would be a huge help.

[image: current diagram without wifi]

Comment: Please draw a schematic of your current situation. A video is no good in this situation because there's no guarantee that the link will be stable over time. Apart from that, not many folk will want to watch a video. If necessary post an image from the video that shows the wiring.

Comment: A Shelly WiFi relay with switch input wired to your existing switch?

Comment: Thanks, can try to draw it but not a pro by any means. As for the shelly, that uses line voltage. I need it to run on 12v dc power from a wall wart. The switch is also a simple toggle, not wall switch.

Comment: Shelly supports 12 V and both toggle and switch. You can configure the behavior yourself.

Comment: Interesting, any mockup taking into consideration the picture I included would be great. I have zero experience with this.